# Devise: Combine SignIn and ForgotPass forms into one

Tags: forms, ruby-on-rails-3.1, devise

As shown in the attached image, I want to combine the Sign In form and the Forgot password form into one form. I am using DEVISE and RoR 3.2.5.

[image]

The Sign In form looks like:

```
= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name), :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal'}) do |f|
  .inputs
    = f.input :login, :required => false, :autofocus => true, :hint => "Enter either email ID or username"
    = f.input :password, :required => false
    = f.input :remember_me, :as => :boolean if devise_mapping.rememberable?
  .form-actions{ :style => "padding-left: 160px;"}
    = f.button :submit, "Sign in", :class => "btn btn-primary"
```

The Forgot password form looks like:

```
= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => password_path(resource_name), :html => { :method => :post }) do |f|
  = f.error_notification
  .inputs
    = f.input :login, :required => true, :hint => "Enter either email ID or username"
  .form-actions{ :style => "padding-left: 160px;"}
    = f.button :submit, "Send me reset password instructions", :class => "btn btn-primary"
```

Comment: Should the user click on the "Forgot your password?" button to recover his password?

Comment: Yes, The UI is one part. We can also add the Forgot Password button next to Sign In, but most importantly I want 1 form and two different submit buttons.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create a new controller method that reads the value of the submit button.

Based on that value, you should be able to route between the 2 distinct actions.

Another -and probably more modern and clean- way would be to attach javascipt onclick events on one of the buttons that will ignore the form action and submit to a different route.

Rough example:

```
<script>
  $('#forgot-submit-button').click(function(){
    $('#my-form').attr('action','<%= forgot_password_path %>').submit()
  });
</script>
```

Not enough time to test this, so please treat it as an example.